# How do I paginate with Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get 50 docs more messages from Cloud Firestore when I click on load more messages button in react-native.

Here is in the below my code get 50 docs when I open up my application, but not all messages.

```
getMessagesFrom(usr){
    return db.collection("ppl/" + usr + "/messages/").orderBy("createdAt", "desc").limit(50).get().then(snapshot => {
        this.docs = snapshot.docs;
        let l = this.docs.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            this.dblid = this.state.myId + usr;
            if (this.msgObj[this.dblid] === undefined) {
                this.msgObj[this.dblid] = [this.docs[i].data()];
            } else {
                this.msgObj[this.dblid] = [...this.msgObj[this.dblid], this.docs[i].data()]
            }
            if (i === l - 1) {
                return this.msgObj;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

My Expectation is getting 50 docs more by clicking on more messages button.

Comment: You can use `startAfter(50)` before `limit`

Comment: Thank you SiSa, I've used but I dont know to keep lastdoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

> Use the startAt() or startAfter() methods to define the start point for a query. The startAt() method includes the start point, while the startAfter() method excludes it.

For managing pages, you can create state for store your page number, and increase it every time you get data

```
const pageSize = 50;     // your page size
state = { pageNum: 0 };  // your page number

getMessagesFrom(usr){
    return db.collection("ppl/" + usr + "/messages/")
      .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
      .startAt(this.state.pageNum * pageSize) // here we set start point
      .limit(pageSize)
      .get().then(snapshot => {

          this.setState({ pageNum: pageNum+1 });

          ...your code

    });
}
```

Comment: How would you paginate "back"? And how would you paginate to a specific index? as in you click on a number: `< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 >`